# postexecute in asynctask is not executing

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    url3="http://www.digitalmarketingbox.com/webtool/boxdata/"+MainActivity.abc+"/updates.zip";

    try {
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        // note : you may also need
        //        HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)
        HttpURLConnection con =(HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        x=con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         x=false;
      }


    try {
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        // note : you may also need
        //        HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)
        HttpURLConnection con =(HttpURLConnection) new URL(url3).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        xc=con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         xc=false;
      }

    //x=exists(params[0]);
    //xc=exists(url3);
    valve=String.valueOf(x);

    if(valve.equals("true"))
    {

    finalurl=url+ MainActivity.abc + "/resources.zip";
    filename="resources.zip";
    MainActivity.fl1=filename;
    Log.i("filename",filename);
    }

    else if(xc==true) 
    {
    finalurl=url+ MainActivity.abc + "/updates.zip";    
    filename="updates.zip";
    MainActivity.fl1=filename;
    Log.i("filename",filename);
    }

    else 
    {
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
         Log.i("url for checking update",url1);
         HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url1); 
         List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reqtype", "resendcontent"));
         parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("menuboxid",MainActivity.abc));
         parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("updatetoken", "dmb20101512"));
         UrlEncodedFormEntity ent;
         ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters,HTTP.UTF_8);
         post.setEntity(ent);
         HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
         HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity(); 
         finalurl=url+ MainActivity.abc + "/updates.zip";   
        filename="updates.zip";
        MainActivity.fl1=filename;
        Log.i("filename",filename);
        Log.i("url",finalurl);
      }
     catch (final IOException e) {      
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finalurl=url+ MainActivity.abc + "/updates.zip";    
    filename="updates.zip";
    MainActivity.fl1=filename;
    }

    try{
        URL url = new URL(finalurl);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();            
        //File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        filedestination=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/" + filename;
        //File file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename);
        File file = new File(filedestination);
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        Log.i("size",String.valueOf(totalSize));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;

            }
        //close the output stream when complete //
        fileOutput.close();
        }
        catch (final IOException e) {       
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("download info","Download complete");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String source = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + filename;
        Log.i("Download destination",source);
        String destination =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/";  
        Log.i("Extract destination",destination);
        try {  
          ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);    
          zipFile.extractAll(destination);  
        } catch (ZipException e) {  
          e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        try
        {
         HttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            Log.i("url is",url1);   
            HttpPost post1 = new HttpPost(url1); 
            List<NameValuePair> parameters1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reqtype", "completeupdate"));
            parameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("menuboxid",MainActivity.abc));
            parameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("updatetoken", "dmb20101512"));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent1 = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters1,HTTP.UTF_8);
            post1.setEntity(ent1);   
            }

         catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
return foo;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stu
super.onPostExecute(result);
//result=bn;
/*if(!result.isEmpty())
{
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
Log.i("AsyncTask finish time",String.valueOf(seconds));
}*/
```

}

i am using this asynctask class in my activity to do some task and checking via the getstatus method that it has finished or not ,but it is never finished
above is my code of my asynctask class and its postexecute is not working can someone expalin me why?

Comment: try removing `super.onPostExecute(result)`

Comment: `protected Object doInBackground(Object... args){
}
protected void onPostExecute(Object arg){
}`
try this.

Comment: it is also not working

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced the same problem. It happens when your Main UI thread goes to sleep. Try to use a timer in your UI thread to keep it awake.